# How can i resize a UITableViewCell based on the height of my CustomCell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, resize, custom-controls

I have a TableView with a CustomCell.In my CustomCell i have some Label's and one Button when ever i am clicking on the Button some of the Label will get hide.Here comes my problem now i need to resize my UITableViewCell based on the CustomCell Height.I know using

```
 - (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)  indexPath
```

i can resize my UITableViewCell.But how can i resize based on my custom cell height.I dont want to use any timer methods. if any one know please help me..

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to adjust a tablecell height:

I remake the cell at the desired index path and adjust the height according to it.

```
- (float) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell.contentView.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: but i need to resize my tableView cells when i am click on the Button inside the CustomCell

Comment: At the moment you click your button you need to do a [yourTableView reloadData] and all will be well.

Comment: But How can i call it From CustomCell file?.
   sorry i am new the objective c.

Comment: You dont have to call anything the delegate will arrange everything for you. And the reloadData you will do in the targetmethod of your button.

Comment: You don't reload your tableview from your cell class. You do it at the place you make your table in. You do know how to fire a method when pressing a button no?

Comment: I know how to fire a method .But my Button is there in CustomCell.
When i am pressing the button it will call a method in CustomCell class.is it possible to reload the table from there? or When i am pressing the Button in CustomCell is it possible call a method in my TableView class?

Comment: You can set the target of any cell button in the class you make your tableview in. (it can be done with delegates too.)